# Append Array from different .txt file

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have 63 .txt file with 26 headers lines and then 19 columns of float data.
I would like to read all the files and store (in row) the first 6 columns of the .txt files (x,y,z,u,v,w). Then for each .txt file I would like to append these data in a new row.

This is the code that I did but after the first j (j=1) then the script crash because the sizes of the arrays are not the same, indeed for some reasons during the first iteration it is skipping not 26 but 52 lines (so also the first 26 of numbers that I want), while in the second is (in a correct way skiiping only 26 headers line).

```
inpDir = "\\ftac\Folder\CD";
files = dir(fullfile(inpDir, '*.txt')); 
n_file = size(files,1); 
for j=1:n_file
    fid = fopen(files(j).name, 'r'); 
    data = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f', 'HeaderLines', 26, 'Delimiter',' ');
    fclose(fid); 
    x(j, :) = data{1}'; % x coordinate 
    y(j, :) = data{2}'; % y coordinate 
    z(j, :) = data{3}'; % y coordinate 
    u(j, :) = data{4}';% u velocity 
    v(j, :) = data{5}'; % v velocity     
    w(j, :) = data{6}'; % w velocity   
end
```

How can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like `readtable` or `readmatrix` with the `'headerlines'` option would make your life much easier

Comment: @Wolfie thanks but I still have the same issue

Comment: Maybe you want `x/y/z/u/v/w` to be cell arrays, so you can assign data like `x{j}` without having to care about whether the dimensions agree with the other files. Then you can sort out combining them into homogeneous arrays later, once all the data is loaded and you can more easily see what the discrepancy is